# Unversioned Files appear from nowhere

Tags: git, android-studio, git-clone

I shifted to Ubuntu from Windows and when i cloned the project from git repository and opened it in android studio, many files appear in un-versioned files. How to get rid of them?

[image: Attached Picture]

Comment: Did the .gitignore file get copied?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `.gitignore` file, cf [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

In your case:

```
# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties


# Android Studio generated files and folders
captures/
.externalNativeBuild/
.cxx/
*.apk
output.json

# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/

# Keystore files
*.jks
*.keystore


# Android Profiling
*.hprof
```